# How to find my realm file?

Tags: realm

I have created a DB by realm and I am not able to find the file as my OS (Yosemite) dont have a mobile folder in the /private/var/mobile.

How should I access my realm to run in the browser?

*Cross posted from google groups*

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705298/7360850) out. This method works for both rooted and unrooted devices.

Answer (score 507, accepted):

## Finding a Realm File

### For Android

[How to view my Realm file in the Realm Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478987/how-to-view-my-realm-file-in-the-realm-browser)

### For iOS

### If your App is on Device

Make sure that your device is connected and go to the devices window in the Xcode menu **Window > Devices** (⌘⇧2). There you will be able to choose your device and your app from a list of installed apps with debugging permissions.

After selecting your app, go to the cog in the toolbar at the bottom of the table view and select **“Download Container…“**. There you will be able to pull the file from the documents location to your Mac. It will be saved as an xcappdata bundle.

When you open the local path in Finder, where you saved it, you can tap into that by selecting **“Show Package Contents”** in the context menu of the finder, when you select the file. A new finder window will open, where you find your Realm inside in the following path (e.g.): AppData/Documents/default.realm (The directory '/private/var/mobile' is the path, which is used by iOS on the device filesystem.

### If your App is on the Simulator

Go to your user’s directory:

`/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<simulator-uuid>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<application-uuid>/Documents/default.realm`

Probably the easiest way to get the current path of the default realm is to pause the simulator and enter the following into the LLDB console:

**Objective-C**:
`(lldb) po [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL`

**Swift using Realm Objective-C**:
`(lldb) po RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration().fileURL`

**Swift using Realm Swift**:
`(lldb) po Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL`

Or if you have an `RLMRealm` instance at hand, you can use:
`(lldb) po myRealm.configuration.fileURL`

Then just copy this path, open your terminal, and type `open` **[Pasted path here]**

**NOTE:** Some paths have a space in them so be sure to use "\" before the space to escape it

#### Helper Tool SimPholders

This is probably the fastest way to find the file of an app in the simulator. Install [SimPholders](http://simpholders.com/). This will allow you to access your app’s documents directory directly from your menu bar.

**Note** Some people have mentioned that SimPholders has taken them to the wrong simulator app folder, if that's the case for you, print out your realm path by following the steps above, printing out your realm.path

Comment: after the latest update there is a error when u do `po RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath()`. It says `called object type 'NSString *' is not a function or function pointer`

Comment: I have the same issue as @carbonr. Can anybody help?

Comment: sorry about that, updated the answer. It comes down to which framework & language you are using

Comment: When I follow the steps to get into the data it asks for an encryption key.

Comment: Objective-C version above 0.97 use
`po [[RLMRealm defaultRealm]path]`

Comment: Part of this answer is outdated now. Here is most recent way to find your realm database file (default.realm) using RealmSwift: `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL`

Comment: Using the RealmSwift method I get the following: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'Realm'`

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Set the debug point in the context where Realm is imported and used.

Comment: iOS app on device: *.realm search finds nothing... seems that the file is not included at all, after downloading the bundle.
Xcode v10.2.1

Comment: Open source alternative to SimPholders: https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim

Comment: Note for iOS users: using `po RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration` has worked for me on when all other options listed here were throwing errors. I have the latest version of all software as of today's date.

Comment: press `command` + `shift` + `.` to see hidden files

Answer (score 140):

I found most simplest way for iOS/macOS 
(for swift 3 Xcode 8.3)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   // for swift 2.0 Xcode 7
   print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
}
```

Then x code will log the correct path, check the screen below.

[image]

Now open your **Finder** and press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (command+shift+G) and paste the **path** that logs on your **Xcode**

Comment: path is deprecated. use `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL` instead

Comment: Its been changed to Realm.configuration.fileURL

Comment: swift 3, xcode8.3 also works with `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!`

Comment: i followed the same process but i can't able to find the file path in finder

Comment: This solution works only with Simulator and not with real devices.

Comment: This is perfect for simulator and once you find your file, it is an easy cmd-click to "Open WIth" to fire up Realm Studio. This begs the question or thought: Realm Studio needs an "open recent" File menu option!

Answer (score 45):

### One Easy Alternative For Simulator Apps

Create a smart folder/search in Finder. Gives quick and easy clickable access to all your realm files.

1. Open the folder `/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` in Finder.

   With terminal `open /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`
2. Search for `.realm`
3. Change the search to look in the `"Devices"` folder only.

[image]

4. Save the search to your sidebar (e.g. as Realms)

[image]

When sorted by date this will give you a quick and easy clickable list of the latest modified Simulator `.realm` files.

Comment: Thanks @Archdoog - not a bad idea when you're going through lots of new projects with Realm

Comment: Saving it as a search is genius! Thank you! :)

Comment: realm can also be searched for using `cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices &&
find . -name '*.realm'`

Answer (score 22):

Here is an easy solution.. I messed with this for awhile. I should point out, this is a specific set of instructions using Android Studio and the AVD Emulator.

1) Start the Emulator and run your app.

2) While the app is still running, open the Android Device Monitor. (its in the toolbar next to the AVD and SDK manager icons)

3) Click the File Explorer tab in the Device Monitor. There should be a lot of folders.

4) Navigate the following path: Data > Data > *Your Package Name* > files > Default.Realm (or whatever you named it)

Ex. If you are using one of the realm example projects, the path would be something like Data>Data>io.realm.examples.realmgridview>files>default.realm

5) Highlight the file, click the Floppy Disk icon in the upper right area "pull a file from the device"

6) Save it off to whereever you want and done.

Answer (score 19):

What I did was to use

```
let realm = Realm(path: "/Users/me/Desktop/TestRealm.realm")
```

and then it gets created in full view on my desktop and I can double-click to launch the Realm Browser on it. Later, I can remove the parameter and let it use the default location when I'm satisfied that all is working as expected.

Comment: I get an error saying " Argument labels '(path:)' do not match any available overloads ". Any idea why?

Comment: Thats just amazing haha!

Comment: Great for testing on the simulator, but probably won't work correctly on a real device.

Comment: let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: URL(string: "/Users/[me]/Desktop/TestRealm.realm")!)

Answer (score 13):

The above answers missing a way to find the realm file in Android platform and believe me this way will save your lot's of time which we generally waste in other approaches to get the realm file. So let's start...

First open "Device File Explorer" in android studio(View -> Tools Windows 
-> Device File Explorer.

This will open your device explorer.

[image]

now open **data -> data -> (your_app_package_name) -> files -> default.realm**

**default.realm** is the file for which we are here. Now Save_as this file at your location and access the file from the realm_browser and you will get your database.

**NOTE: Mentioned approach is tested on non-rooted phone(one+3).**

Answer (score 11):

Objective-C -    `[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL`

```
NSLog(@"%@",[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL);
```

> Eg-/Users/"Your-user-name"/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E58645FF-90DE-434D-B2EB-FA145EB6F2EA/data/Containers/Data/Application/E427BD21-2CB1-4F64-9ADF-8742FF731209/Documents/

This is the simplest command you can run to get your path to .realm file. You will see the .realm file after all your read and write operations are completed.

Or

You can you open source [openSim](https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim/releases), alternative of [simpholders](https://simpholders.com/) to access your app’s documents directory directly from your menu bar

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the default Realm DB in simulator:

```
po Realm().configuration.fileURL
```

Comment: Can you add some details?

Comment: @zeeshan please pause your simulator while running, and type the command in, then press enter.

Answer (score 9):

## Updated answer to the newest Realm:

### For Android:

checkout stetho and https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm 
Video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pFJz5VexRw

### For IOS (Swift)

Either:

```
debugPrint("Path to realm file: " + realm.configuration.fileURL!.absoluteString)
```

### or

**Step 1:** Have a constant called dev somewhere. Let's say Constant file

```
public class Constants {

    public static var dev: Bool = true

}
```

**Step 2:** Create another class called RealmFunctions.swift

```
import RealmSwift


func realmAndPath() -> Realm {
    if Constants.dev {
        // location of my desktop
        let testRealmURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/#####/Desktop/TestRealm.realm")
        return try! Realm(fileURL: testRealmURL)
    } else {
        return try! Realm()
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** finally in your view controller:

```
let realm = realmAndPath()
```

thanks to Stewart Lynch for the original answer

Comment: for swift 3 i needed to change `realm.path` to `realm.configuration.fileURL!.absoluteString`

Answer (score 5):

**If you are getting 'Enter Encryption Key' dialog box error:**

I am using Swift 2.1 with Realm 0.96.2 and was getting this error when trying to open the database file:

> 'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a
>   compatible file format. If you know the file is encrypted, you can
>   manually enter its encryption key to open it.

Found that using the pre-release version of the Realm Browser 0.96 fixed the issue:

https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96-prerelease

Answer (score 5):

**2020: Realm file on iOS Real device (Not simulator)**

Starts from the menu bar at the top then follow the sequence below: -

1. Window
2. Devices and Simulators
3. Select Device
4. At the bottom find the title  (INSTALLED APPS)

   *Note: Scroll down or enlarge the Devices and simulators pop up window to see the list of installed apps.*
5. Select Your app.
6. Tap the gear button (*It's located at the bottom of the apps list*)
7. Download Container
8. Choose location to save it.
9. Right click on the downloaded file
10. Show Package contents
11. AppData

That's it from there you can access Your Realm files depending on your configuration. For example if you saved in Documents or Library folders simply open it to see your realms.

Answer (score 3):

I found my realm file by issuing this command in Terminal:
`sudo find / -name "*.realm"`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

First, I acknowledge that this is an Android thread but it is the first search result for this issue in general.

To open the most recently created Xcode Simulator Realm db in Realm Browser you can use this script in Automator or type it all in at the terminal.  By using Automator, I have one-click access to my current realm.

```
    cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
    cd `ls -t | head -n 1`/data/Containers/Data/Application
    cd `ls -t | head -n 1`/Documents    
    open -a 'Realm Browser' ./default.realm
```

Install Realm Browser.
In Automator, click New, select Run Shell Script, paste in code, change Realm Db name, Click Run to test, save file somewhere convenient for quick click access.

I don't know where I found this tip the first time but this thread reminded me how I was accessing my live data in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Just for your App is on the iOS Simulator

Enter

```
console.log (Realm.defaultPath)
```

in the code eg: App.js

Answer (score 3):

As previously was mentioned you can use next approaches to find file location

```
//code
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL 

//lldb
(lldb) po Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
```

or you can manually find it:

```
//Simulator
/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<simulator-uuid>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<application-uuid>/Documents/

//for example
/Users/alex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1D084B0-CD97-41B4-871F-E131CA33F635/data/Containers/Data/Application/373721C7-2381-4E3D-9ABC-2147F748322F/Documents/

//iPhone (download a copy)
Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Devices -> <select device and app> -> App container actions -> Download Container... -> <selectfolder and navigate to it (.xcappdata)> -> Right Click -> Show Package Consents -> AppData -> Documents
```

*Please note that if you set file name for realm and it has some other extension than `.realm` `RealmStudio` does not open it by default

Answer (score 2):

I have taken this one step further.
I have created a swift file called **RealmFunctions** and in it, I have created this function

```
    import RealmSwift
    func realmAndPath() -> Realm {
        if dev {
            // location of my desktop
            return try! Realm(path: "/Users/slynch/Desktop/TestRealm.realm")
        } else {
            return try! Realm()
        }
    }
```

Now in my main view controller, I have a global boolean variable called dev

```
var dev: Bool = true // when in development mode
var dev: Bool = false // when I want to run on my device or upload to app stor.
```

Now, all I have to do in my code is

```
let realm = realmAndPath()
```

So when in development mode, I can find my realm database on my desktop and can open in Realm Browser.

Comment: Error:(13, 21) argument labels '(path:)' do not match any available overloads, seems it changed in the newer versions

Answer (score 2):

For those using React Native and using the default realm:

`Realm.defaultPath`

Comment: I can not find this!

Comment: @Natividad where to put this code ? any suggestions on getting realm file?

Comment: @AliHesari did you find sth ?

Comment: `componentDidMount() { console.log(Realm.defaultPath) }` in my component using Realm worked for me.  Check xcode console for path afterwards.

Comment: In a function component I place it after `Realm.open(config)`

for example like this `console.log('* REALM PATH: ' + Realm.defaultPath);`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
func getFilePath() -> URL? {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.configuration.fileURL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find your realm file from **real iOS device**

Worked for me in **Xcode 12**

Steps -

1. In Xcode, go to **Window -> Devices and Simulators**
2. Select your device from the left side list
3. Select your app name under the Installed apps section
4. Now, highlight your app name and click on the gear icon below it
5. from the dropdown select the **Download Container** option
6. Select the location where you want to save the file
7. Right-click on the file which you just saved and select **Show Package Contents**
8. Inside the App Data folder navigate to the folder where you saved your file.

Comment: This seems outdated, as in XCode 12.4 there is no list of installed apps in the Simulators/device section

Answer (score 1):

To get the DB path for iOS, the simplest way is to:

1. Launch your app in a simulator
2. Pause it at any time in the debugger
3. Go to the console (where you have `(lldb)`) and type: `po RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath`

Tada...you have the path to your realm database

Answer (score 1):

The correct (lldb) command is: `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Tools -> Android Device Monitor

And under File Explorer.  Search for the apps.  And the file is under data/data.

Answer (score 0):

The correct lldb command for Xcode 7, Swift 2.2+ is `po Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!`

Comment: the member is not call `path` but `fileURL` : Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!

Comment: you are correct...this changed in realm1.0...i was using version 0.98 when i answered this...correct answer is

`po Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.3 solution

Easier solution that won't break with Realm updates

```
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    print("App Path: \(dirPaths)")
```

The .realm file should be inside "Documents"

Answer (score 0):

all the steps for android and ios can be found on the official realm website:
https://support.realm.io/support/solutions/articles/36000064525-how-do-i-locate-realm-files-on-a-device-or-simulator-

Answer (score 0):

Although the question itself is for iOS, the title is pretty generic as such that it got me here. So, I have felt the need to share a solution for Windows here.

In dotnet C#, use `realm.Config.DatabasePath` to see where the realm file is located. If not set differently, then it is `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\default.realm` along with `default.realm.management` folder and `default.realm.lock`

To set a new path, adapt this code (folders must exists, or gives error)

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(new RealmConfiguration(optionalPath: "C:/myproject/myrealm/myproject.realm" ));
```