# I cannot get "default.realm" file in my iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, realm

I want to access the Realm data file which is created on iOS Simulator. With the instruction of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file), I got to the following directory:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0AB2D954-A3D5-4ABF-A5C5-CC470FB4ABDE/data/Containers/Data/Application/7192723E-7582-48EB-8B66-14E1073D7CE6/Documents
```

However, the directory has only the following Realm files:

```
default.realm.note
default.realm.log_a
default.realm.log_b
default.realm.log
default.realm.lock
```

and I cannot find the Realm file `default.realm`.

Also, when I open up the Realm Browser and access to the directory, all the files above except `default.realm.note` is grayed-out and I cannot access the Realm data.

Note that I create a Realm instance and save data by `realm.write`:

```
try! self.realm.write {
    for (_, value) in json { // json is from SwiftyJSON
        let pitcher = Player()
        player.year.value = value["year"].int
        player.name = value["name"].stringValue

        self.realm.add(player)
    }
}
```

So how can I access the Realm data file?

Comment: You can use this app https://github.com/somegeekintn/SimDirs

Comment: @blaszard Could you please make sure what does `print(self.realm.path)` show? And can you show the code around instantiating `self.realm` instance?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Forgive me that I'm late to reply, but I found `print(self.realm.path)` returns different paths between launches. As to your second question, I instantiated `let realm = try! Realm()`, which is the way it is instantiated in sample projects.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi I should have clarified; the path is different in XXX of `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0AB2D954-A3D5-4ABF-A5C5-CC470FB4ABDE/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXX/Documents`, and the contents under `Documents/` still lack `default.realm`.

Answer (score 0):

Realm's [auxiliary files](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#auxiliary-realm-files) (`.note`, `.lock`, etc) are always created next to the `.realm` file itself. So it seems like *something* is deleting the realm file without deleting the auxiliary files, which would explain why you can't find it.

Please make sure you're not deleting this Realm file somewhere in your code.