# Issue finding default realm file in RealmSwift iOS 7 Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am having a major issue when trying to integrate realm into a project with Swift 2 in Xcode 7. I am trying to find the default.realm file so that I can usually see the DB in Realm Browser.

So far I have scoured the internet and tried the following solutions...

[How to find my realm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file)

Solution option 1:

Tried printing the file path to the console, comes up with errors that I cannot solve, used the following print commands

```
print(Realm().path)
```

and then...

```
let realm = Realm(path: "/Users/me/Desktop/TestRealm.realm")
```

Solution option 2:

Tried pausing the simulator and putting this into the LLDB console...

> po Realm.defaultPath

which returns...

> error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Realm'
>   Realm.defaultPath

For reference here are the files that create the realm objects

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class XMCMovie: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var tomatometer = 0
    dynamic var consensus = ""
    dynamic var imageName = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(id: NSString, title: NSString, tomatometer: Int, consensus: NSString, imageName: NSString) {
        super.init()

        self.id = id as String
        self.title = title as String
        self.tomatometer = tomatometer
        self.consensus = consensus as String
        self.imageName = imageName as String
    }
}

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class XMCApi {

    class func requestOpeningMovies() {
        let movies = [ XMCMovie(id: "0", title: "The Hobbit: The Battle Of The Five Armies", tomatometer: 62, consensus: "Suitably grim, epic, and action-packed, The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies ends Peter Jackson's second Middle-earth trilogy on a rousing high note.", imageName: "hobbit"),
            XMCMovie(id: "1", title: "Night At The Museum: Secret Of The Tomb", tomatometer: 53, consensus: "No consensus yet.", imageName: "museum"),
            XMCMovie(id: "2", title: "Annie", tomatometer: 20, consensus: "The new-look Annie hints at a progressive take on a well-worn story, but smothers its likable cast under clichés, cloying cuteness, and a distasteful materialism.", imageName: "annie"),
            XMCMovie(id: "3", title: "Mr. Turner", tomatometer: 97, consensus: "Led by a masterful performance from Timothy Spall and brilliantly directed by Mike Leigh, Mr. Turner is a superior Hollywood biopic.", imageName: "turner"),
            XMCMovie(id: "4", title: "Song Of The Sea", tomatometer: 100, consensus: "No consensus yet.", imageName: "sea") ]

        // Write our movie objects to the database
        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write() {

            for movie in movies {
                /*  This method will avoid duplicating records by looking at the
                primary key we've set on our object. Go look at the XMCMovie
                class to see that method defined.
                */

                // XMCMovie.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(movie)

                // Alternatively, you could add new objects by calling this method
                realm.add(movie)
                // or
                // realm.addObjects(movies) // An array of objects
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any guidance about where to find a solution to this problem that would be wonderful. Thanks!

-RB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little tweaking, I was able to find the answer. So I will post the print command that worked for me. *Note: this is in Swift 2.1.1*

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
```

Cheers,

-RB

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you need to use the `try!` keyword since `Realm()` can throw an error:

`print(try! Realm().path)`

or in the debugger:

`po try! Realm().path`

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question but I leave this answer just in case it would be useful for somebody. This worked for me with Swift 2.2

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```