# How do I start up Realm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx

I ran a `git clone` on the above `GitHub` so it's in my projects directory.

I downloaded the the `Realm Browser` app from the `App Store` but now I'm trying to use it in my `React Native` project.  On the `GitHub` page (above), it says that `Realm Browser is a small utility for Mac OS X that lets you open .realm files to view and modify their contents`.

What `.realm` files are there to open?  The items I want to put in `Realm` aren't in `.realm` files, they're inside my `.js` file.  How would I go about fixing this?

Here's my `.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Third from './Third';

class Second extends Component {
    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'Third' // .js file name
        });
    }

    render() {
        const Realm = require('realm');

        class Email {}
        Email.schema = {
            name: 'Email',
            primaryKey: 'name',
            properties: {
                name: 'string',
            },
        };

        const realm = new Realm({schema: [Email]});

// Query
        let email = realm.objects('Email');
        // email.length // => 0

// Write
        realm.write(() => {
            email = realm.create('Email', {
                name: 'something'
            });

            realm.create('Email', {name: "else"}, true);
        });

        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" email"}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" password"}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20 // makes button horizontally longer.
    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 4

    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#9b42f4',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#41bbf4',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 10
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

export default Second;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find my realm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file)

Comment: Realm Browser can be used to inspect `.realm` files stored on a device (iOS or Android). I guess what you are trying to look for is the `Realm Object Server`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need the `default.realm` file so I can drag & drop it into `Xcode` in my project directory but I can't find it.

Comment: The file is automatically created for you when you first launch you iOS app, you don't need to add it to your project.

Comment: @DávidPásztor But I don't see it in my project.  This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS6YCq2OdeA shows what I'm talking about.  This is the part I'm missing.  Skip to part 1:34.