# Open Realm Studio on React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I would like run Realm Studio on my React Native App. On here video, i see file Places.realm, but i don't know on i generate this file ? (https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/)

Anyone have already work with Realm on React Native ?

Thank you !

Comment: On iOS this could probably work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file

Answer (score 3):

For iOS simulator:

Place this code somewhere in your RN app to find out the location of realm file.

```
import Realm from 'realm';
      Realm.open({}).then((realm) => {
        console.log('Realm is located at: ' + realm.path);
      });
```

This will print the location of the default realm file in console.
Go to the directory in which default file located at ( you can `cd` then `open`  with terminal)

The directory will contain one or more files that could be opened with Realm Studio. One file will contain your data sent to the Realm DB from RN app.

Reference : [Doc](https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/realm-studio/view-your-data)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to examine your Realm using Realm Studio, you can enable sync (see property `sync` in https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#~Configuration) and set up an object server (https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/developer-edition/).

The alternative is to use Chrome and debugging as with any other React Native app.