# Get realm database remotely Android

Tags: android, realm

We have a set of internally managed devices that use Realm to manage their DB. Recently we noticed an issue on some of the devices but need the database to confirm the problem.

Is there anyway we can remote into the device to get this database downloaded?

Comment: This called back door and this is a huge hole in security model. So normally there should not be any way to do this. But If you implement such functionality in your app this is possible. Realm db is just a file, so adding functionality to upload the file to remote endpoint is easy. there is Realm Browser app for desktop to discover content of db file. Also if you have root permission you can access the file with adb.

Comment: It's an internal app never to be released so back door not a problem

Comment: in this case this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50246843/2290950

Comment: As its remote will this match the path on the device>