# Why can't I find the directory on my computer for the default.realm file for the connection to Realm Studio?

Tags: swift, realm

The file directory I am getting when doing the

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

is as follows:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/825DF5F3-AF1E-47B6-80C4-D3CCCC90CD8C/Documents/default.realm
```

Now, the strange thing is that when I do the Shift+Command+G to copy this into my finder then it only shows me the var directory, which does not contain the "mobile" directory. Also, when I do a search for the .realm file there is no such file on my Mac. Can somebody telling me what's going on?

Comment: still not finding the file. I can find the  file:///var/ directory , but in there is no "mobile directory (I also checked hidden files) .

Comment: I noticed that in all references to this topic the file path is something like this:     /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<simulator-uuid>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<application-uuid>/Documents/default.realm..........so, why is my Xcode/Realm creating a different file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I finally figured it out. I ran my app on my iPhone because I can't use the simulator since I need the camera. This is why it gave me the var/mobile directory. I found this detailed explanation about what to do when the app runs on the device rather than the simulator: [How to find my realm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file/28465803#28465803).