# Unable to Locate Realm File on Device

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

I am attempting to locate the realm DB file on my device (iPhone) and I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465803/6792327) and [here](https://support.realm.io/support/solutions/articles/36000064525-how-do-i-locate-realm-files-on-a-device-or-simulator-). However, I do not see any realm files in the folder `AppData/Documents`.

I print out the URL path as I run the app on my device and my simulator, and this is what I see:

```
//On device
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C7332EE4-1567-4C96-8392-7FBD0DC9C863/DB/default.realm

//On simulator
/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D205C50D-F432-4A1F-80CB-FB3D91E0A1EA/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/5E67A740-A338-4583-9B9D-461F5D1A734A/DB/default.realm
```

The URL written on the simulator appears to be any default URL where the Realm DB is written to. I can't seem to understand why can't I find the realm file at `AppData/Documents` on the actual device.

Answer (score 3):

Realm files are only created on disk when you call `Realm()` for the first time. Once you've created an instance of Realm, you can find the exact file route of that Realm by printing out `realm.configuration.fileURL`. You can normally use `Realm.Configuration` to set a different location of the Realm file on disk as opposed to the `Documents` directory.

Both of those file paths you displayed show that the file is located in a folder named `DB` and it appears to be in an app group (eg, a shared folder between apps and extensions) instead of your app's default `Documents` directory.

So with that being said, it would appear that somewhere in your app, a custom `Realm.Configuration` object is being used to create the Realm file somewhere else, which would explain why you can't find it in `Documents`.